# neo4j ExecutionResult: Extract multiple columns (since javaColumnAs only works once)

Tags: java, neo4j

I am currently doing a cyper query like this:

```
StringBuilderStringLogger logger = new StringBuilderStringLogger(new StringBuilder());
GraphDatabaseService neo4jDb = database.getDatabase();
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (n:Person{name:'Test'}) MATCH n-[r]->m RETURN n,r,m;");
```

So now I want to get out n, r and m. So I tried like the following:

```
Node node = IteratorUtil.single(result.javaColumnAs("n"));
Relationship relationship = IteratorUtil.single(result.javaColumnAs("r"));
Node otherNode = IteratorUtil.single(result.javaColumnAs("m"));
```

Now this does not seem to work. Fhe first request always works, but the second one will return an empty iterator and therefore null for the relationship or object.
The reason for this is, that ExecutionResul is a lazy iterator. So if you go through it once (like with javaColumnAs, which iterates over it), then you can not get anything out of it afterwards. Where I find this explanation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/neo4j/javacolumnAs/neo4j/oUP_2b8mAlY/Sp39sfYm9_4J

Now if I do it this way, it works correctly.

```
Node node = null;
Relationship relationship = null;
Node otherNode = null;

for (Map<String, Object> row : IteratorUtil.asIterable(result.javaIterator())) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet()) {

        switch (column.getKey()){
            case "n":
                node = (Node) column.getValue();
                break;
            case "r":
                relationship = (Relationship) column.getValue();
                break;
            case "m":
                otherNode = (Node) column.getValue();
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ");
    }
}
```

Now I hope that I am not the only one that thinks that this does not look as nice as the code that I tried first. Now is there any way to do this nicer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're returning multiple columns, just pick them up by name from the row (which is a Map where the key is the column name, and the value is the column value):

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
   node = (Node) row.get("n");        
   relationship = (Relationship) row.get("r");
   otherNode = (Node) row.get("m"); 
}
```

PS: You probably just posted an example but please always parameterize your queries

Comment: Now I feel stupid :D Why did I not figure out that this would be the way to go :). Could even just get the first row and then get the columns.